# How to exit a build after the test passes on travis CI

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

[image]

[image]

Attached is a pic of my package.json and travis file.
how can I stop or exit the build after all my test has passed?
the build doesn't stop after all the test has been pass.

Comment: I also stuck here. Did you found any answer?

Comment: add --exit in your package.json

Comment: I am confused. In which line should I add  --exit in package.json?